# Show only left and right border

Tags: css, javafx, border

How can I get a border for a VBox, that shows only left and right borders?

```
.warning-box {
    -fx-border-width: 4;
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-style: dashed;
}
```

I use this in a table, if multiple rows contain warning cells, I would like to omit the top and/ or bottom border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify different colors or widths for top&bottom and left&right:

```css
.warning-box {
    -fx-border-width: 4;
    -fx-border-color: transparent red transparent red;
    -fx-border-style: dashed;
}
```

or

```css
.warning-box {
    -fx-border-width: 0 4 0 4;
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-style: dashed;
}
```

If there are 4 space seperated values instead of a single one (for properties where this is applicable), the values are used for the top, right, bottom and left parts respectively.